# Operations on elements of column vectors

Tags: r

I have a column vector containing 1's. I also have another numeric column containing numbers.

Example:

```
day_eq   day
1         1
1         5
1         3
1         2
```

I now want to say: 
If an element from day is smaller than its corresponding element in day_eq, 
make invalid (a column vector element) = 5.

This is my code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(setin)){
        if (setin[[i,"day"]]<setin[[i,"day_eq"]]){
            setin[[i,"valid"]] = 0
            setin[[i,"invalid_code"]] = 5 
        }
        }
```

It isn't working. It keeps saying:

```
Error in if (setin[[i, "day"]] < setin[[i, "day_eq"]]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

or

```
In if (test.ID1$day_eq > test.ID1$day) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Where test.ID1 is the set name.

Comment: using your example, the code runs without error. it doesn't do anything, but I can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for that. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing... but `ifelse` should be able to help you...

```
setin$valid <- ifelse(setin$day < setin$day_eq, 0, NA)
setin$invalid_code <- ifelse(setin$day < setin$day_eq, 5, NA)
```

Comment: I don't see why you need two steps here. You could also write `setin$valid <- ifelse(setin$day < setin$day_eq, 5, NA)`

Answer (score 0):

your data is

```
day_eq <- c(1,1,1,1)
day <- c (1,5,3,2)
setin <- data.frame(day_eq,day)
```

the solution using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
setin %>% mutate(invalid  = ifelse (day < day_eq, 5, 0))
```

I used `setin` as set name, however, you also use `test.ID1`, so just replace it in case